Microsoft Graph API fails to update user birthday and hireDate in GCC high environment
I have a spring batch job that is scheduled to update the hireDate and birthday attributes of a user profile in SharePoint using MS Graph API in the GCC high environment. Below are the details:
PATCH API - https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}
Payload used -
{
    "hireDate": "2024-07-01T00:00:00Z",
    "birthday": "1982-09-22T00:00:00Z"
}

Below is the snapshot of the API permissions configured in the Azure portal for the registered application.
API permissions for the registered application
A sample response received is as follows:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-08-21T16:15:24",
            "request-id": "8997d5a6-14d6-4d37-94d3-a05470210bfa",
            "client-request-id": "8997d5a6-14d6-4d37-94d3-a05470210bfa"
        }
    }
}

This API was working fine until Aug 7, 2024. Can anyone please help me understand what has changed or what am I doing wrong here?
I have added all the API permissions to registered application in Azure portal. I have also reached out the Microsoft community platform to understand the issue.

Why did you grant delegated and application permissions? Do you authenticate on behalf of a user or with client secret/certificate?

Yes, I authenticate using a client secret/certificate

Just to close this request, it seems Microsoft realized the issue and put in a fix for it. It is working fine now. No changes were made in the code.

This error is because of the issue with the role that you have in your token. For some properties to get updated you need to have higher privileges as suggested in this microsoft documentation.
Try adding Sites.ReadWrite.All permission to update the hireDate as it is a  property specifically for used for Sharepoint in Microsoft 365. Have a look at the properties documentation.

I added the "Sites.ReadWrite.All" permission but it did not help. Still getting the same error. However, while doing some R&D on this issue, I realized that I can use "employeeHireDate" in place of "hireDate" to update the value. This attribute now works fine. But, the "birthday" attribute is still having issues.

Let me check and get back to you on birthday.

@user220982 Could you please share the permissions that you have in the token that you are using?

"roles": [
"User.ReadWrite.All",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All",
"Sites.ReadWrite.All",
"User.Read.All",
"User.EnableDisableAccount.All",
"User.ManageIdentities.All",
"Sites.FullControl.All"
]

@user220982 Please add Directory.AccessAsUser.All and try to update only birthday property. Don't include hireDate or employeeHireDate.

Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission is only available for Delegated access and not Application.

Ok. I see in this document that it can be assigned that role. Let me see if there are other ways. According to this blog the patch can happen. Can you try this same request in Graph Explorer and let me know what are the results.

The challenge is, all the posts are referencing to "https://graph.microsoft.com". Whereas, I am using the GCC High environment "https://graph.microsoft.us". Also, there is no Graph Explorer developer environment for GCC High.

It will work with graph.microsoft.us in a normal Graph Explorer and let me know the results.

The url is not allowed in graph explorer. It expects graph.microsoft.com
